# Getting smooth fade in for many elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have a gallery page which displays a whole bunch of photo thumbnails (>50) and I want each image to fade in as it loads. I've managed to get it to work, but the fade in effect gets really jerky once I'm trying to fade in more than 20 or so images at the same time. Is there a better way to do fade-ins for large number elements smoothly?

Right now what I'm doing is using css transitions so each element originally has

```
.aThumbnail {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

then in code i do

```
aThumbnail.onload = function(){
  this.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1. If these are small images that don't take long to load, then I would recommend only fading the first twenty or so. If you are talking about potentially hundreds of animations going at once (since each depends purely on when it loads), then I could see why that would bog down the speed.
2. Another option is to reduce your time to a half or even quarter of second fade in, so the transitions finish sooner while others are beginning.
3. Last, set different classes for "groups" of them, where some groups are "paused" before they ever start loading. This way, group 1 loads first, and when it is done, then group 2, etc.